# C# - Fastest Way To Sort Array Of Primitives And Track Their Indices

Tags: c#, performance, sorting, primitive

I need a `float[]` to be sorted. And I need to know where the old indices are in new array. That's why I can't use `Array.Sort();` or whatever. So I would like to write a function that sorts the array for me and remembers from what index it took each value:

```
float[] input  = new float[] {1.5, 2, 0, 0.4, -1, 96, -56, 8, -45};
// sort
float[] output; // {-56, -45, -1, 0, 0.4, 1.5, 2, 8, 96};
int[] indices; // {6, 8, 4, 2, 3, 0, 1, 7, 5};
```

Size of arrays would be around 500. How should I approach this ? What sorting algorithm etc.

---

**After solved:** It always surprises me how powerful C# is. I didn't even though of it being able to do that task on it's own. And since I already heard that `Array.Sort()` is very fast I'll take it.

Comment: About the indices... Wouldn't it be easier to just save the input list, sort the output and then compare indexes between the both? There's no size difference in memory between a float and int, so it won't const you any memory.

Comment: @Tophe Are you sure it would be the quickest way ?

Comment: Not sure, and it's not as slick as the accepted answer. But depending on how often you need do get the original indexes it might be more effective to actually compare indexes rather than looping through every list at creation - since the input list already contains the original indexes. That gives you one less instruction to do every time. Probably, though, you'll get a smoother way of grabbing the values other ways.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
float[] input = new float[] { 1.5F, 2, 0, 0.4F, -1, 96, -56, 8, -45 };
int[] indices = new int[input.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < indices.Length; i++) indices[i] = i;
Array.Sort(input, indices);
// input and indices are now at the desired exit state
```

Basically, the 2-argument version of `Array.Sort` applies the same operations to **both** arrays, running the actual *sort* comparisons on the first array. This is normally used the other way around - to rearrange something by the desired indices; but this works too.

Comment: Thanks for an example without `Linq` and with good explanation.

Comment: A List<KeyValuePair<int,float>> and a custom sorter would also work

Comment: @tinstaafl but would be more complicated, require duplication of the original data (note I never duplicated the floats); wouldn't actually sort the original array; and would be less direct (via the comparer) and thus I would *expect* less performant (not verified)

Answer (score 5):

You can use the overload of Array.Sort() which takes TWO arrays, and sorts the second one according to how it sorted the first one:

```
float[] input  = new [] { 1.5f, 2, 0, 0.4f, -1, 96, -56, 8, -45 };
int[] indices = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length).ToArray();
Array.Sort(input, indices);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create a new array of indices, and then sort both of them using Array.Sort and treating `input` as keys:

```
float[] input = new float[] { 1.5F, 2, 0, 0.4F, -1, 96, -56, 8, -45 };
int[] indicies = Enumerable.Range(0, input.Length).ToArray();
Array.Sort(input, indicies);
```

Answer (score 0):

if you use linq:

```
    float[] input = new float[] { 1.5F, 2, 0, 0.4F, -1, 96, -56, 8, -45 };

    var result = input.Select(x => new { Value = x, Index = input.ToList().IndexOf(x)}).OrderBy(x => x.Value).ToList();

    // sort
    float[] output = result.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
    int[] indices = result.Select(x => x.Index).ToArray();
```

in results you got objects with values and their indexes.

Comment: You realize that does an `input.ToList` *per input element*, and fails to give the correct results if there are duplicates? There is actually an overload of `Select` that *hands you* the index of each item - `.Select((x,i) => new { Value = x, Index = i })` would be much better. But in this case, `Array.Sort` is all that is needed, anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

A `List<KeyValuePair<int,float>>` and a custom sorter would also work.  the key for each pair holds the original index.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {           
        List<KeyValuePair<int,float>> data = new List<KeyValuePair<int,float>>
        {
             new KeyValuePair<int,float>(0,1.5f),
             new KeyValuePair<int,float>(1,2),
             new KeyValuePair<int,float>(2,0),
             new KeyValuePair<int,float>(3,0.4f),
             new KeyValuePair<int,float>(4,-1),
             new KeyValuePair<int,float>(5,96),
             new KeyValuePair<int,float>(6,-56),
             new KeyValuePair<int,float>(7,8),
             new KeyValuePair<int,float>(8,-45)
        };
        data.Sort(SortByValue);
        foreach (KeyValuePair<int, float> kv in data)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(kv.Key.ToString() + " - " + kv.Value.ToString());
        }


    }
    private int SortByValue(KeyValuePair<int, float> a, KeyValuePair<int, float> b)
    {
        return a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value);
    }
```