# Most efficient way to sort an array and keep corresponding original indices

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, indices

I want to sort an array of ints in C#, but also keep the original indices corresponding to each element in the array.

My first thought is to convert to a Dictionary object with the key as the index and the value as the value; and then sort by value using linq. I don't think this performs very well. What other solutions are possible? Performance is key here.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17399917/c-sharp-fastest-way-to-sort-array-of-primitives-and-track-their-indices?rq=1) seems to be a nice and easy solution; but is it the fastest way to do it?

Comment: _"is it the fastest way to do it?"_ - depends on your data and machine. [Measure it](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/).

Answer (score 1):

If you talking about performance in time, you can copy array into the second array, sort second array and then use two arrays for separate functionality. This will give you `O(1)` access to needed elements.

If you talking about performance in terms of space, your approach with a Dictionary is the best as it will only keep 1 copy of the elements resulting in `O(n)` space.

As usual, don't optimise until you actually hit a performance problem.

Comment: I am talking about performance in time, and the efficiency of the sorting algorithm as opposed to accessing the elements.

Comment: @ArmenSafieh-Garabedian sorting algorithms will perform in `O(n*log(n))` - there is nothing you can do faster in a general case. So Array.Sort or Linq will perform at ~ same speed, with array probably a bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

There is a set of specific built-in functions for doing this in **.NET**. Look for the overloads of [Array.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_) that take a `TKey[]` argument. There are several overloads that let you specify a subrange to sort, or a custom `IComparer<TKey>`. The secret is to is pass in your original array as the `keys` argument, and an identity array (`0, 1, 2,... n-1`) for the `items` argument. The following function will do all the work for you:

```
/// sort array 'rg', returning the original index positions
static int[] SortAndIndex<T>(T[] rg)
{
    int i, c = rg.Length;
    var keys = new int[c];
    if (c > 1)
    {
        for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
            keys[i] = i;

        System.Array.Sort(rg, keys /*, ... */);
    }
    return keys;
}
```

Again, with `Array.Sort`, notice that we're careful about the possibly confusing parameter names. We pass our **items** in as the first parameter (which is called "keys"), and our **index-to-be** (which feel more like keys) is passed in as the second parameter (called "items").

Usage is pretty self-explanatory:

```
var rgs = new[] { "xyz", "a", "", "bb", "pdq" };

int[] idx = SortAndIndex(rgs);  // rgs: { "",  "a", "bb", "pdz", "xyz" }
                                // idx: {  2,   1,    3,    4,     0   }
```

This covers the OP's case where you actually want the original data to end up sorted. If that's what you need, you can stop reading here.

But a related issue is, *what if you want those same sort indicies, but you **don't want to modify the original array?*** How do we get the sort indices without changing the order of original items?

The best way I've found to do this is to in fact use the procedure above to sort the data and obtain the index, but then ***use that sort index to restore the sorted items back to their original order***.

There are probably a few ways to do this, but since this question mentioned efficiency, I can show some code that's guaranteed to perform the minimal number of original-item swaps, while using just a single `T` element of storage, in order to restore items back to their original, unsorted order:

```
static unsafe void RevertSortIndex<T>(T[] rg, int[] keys)
{
    int i, k, c;
    int* rev = stackalloc int[c = rg.Length];
    for (i = 0; i < c; i++)
        rev[k = keys[i]] = k != i ? i : -1;

    do
        if ((i = rev[--c]) != c && i >= 0)
        {
            T t = rg[k = c];
            do
            {
                rg[k] = rg[i];
                rev[k] = -1;
            }
            while ((i = rev[k = i]) != c);

            rg[k] = t;
            rev[k] = -1;
        }
    while (c > 0);
}
```

In order to just use a single `T` element for swapping, and also move each element only once into its final position, you have to do the swapping in a very specific order determined by the data. Figuring this out is simplified by a temporary reverse index (`rev`), which is easy to create from `keys`. Here it's shown as [stackalloc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/stackalloc), but if you don't want to go that route, you can easily replace it with a managed `int[]` allocation.

Without going into too much detail, any sort index contains one or more loops (or circular "chains") of items that link from one to another, and following each of these loops gives you an optimal order in which you can restore those elements to their original positions while keeping only a single temporary `T`. This is what the inner `do...while` loop does.

The outer `while...` loop is needed to scan for additional loops because the sort index as a whole may have multiple independent chains, and they all need to be visited. Importantly, for correct results each chain must be processed exactly once and no more. So, in order to find out whether any given swap has already been handled, its entry in the `rev` temporary reverse index is set to `-1`. This indicates that the corresponding `T` element in `rg` has already been moved (as part of a previous chain).

Here's the complete usage example:

```
var rgs = new[] { "xyz", "a", "", "bb", "pdq" };

int[] idx = SortAndIndex(rgs);

// rgs: { "",  "a", "bb", "pdz", "xyz" }
// idx: {  2,   1,    3,    4,     0   }

RevertSortIndex(rgs, idx);

// rgs: { "xyz", "a", "", "bb", "pdq"  }
// idx: {   2,   1,    3,    4,     0  }    (unchanged)
```

A final note would be that the combination of `SortAndIndex` with `RevertSortIndex` may give the outward appearance that `rgs` ultimately ends up unmodified, but this should not be relied upon for concurrency purposes. If `rgs` is simultaneously visible from elsewhere, interim states will be visible.

Answer (score 1):

While old-school and un-typed [Array.Sort(Array keys, Array items)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.7#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_) it is better than LINQ for tracking the index.

Getting into the Array implementation:

- [C#](http://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs) Github source code for Array
- [CPP](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/array.cpp) The platform implementation parts
- [Matt Warren](http://mattwarren.org/2017/05/08/Arrays-and-the-CLR-a-Very-Special-Relationship/) - if you really want to understand Array

## Array.Sort vs Linq

```
    [GlobalSetup]
    public virtual void Setup()
    {
        data = new T[N];
        indexes = new int[N];
        for (var cc = 0; cc < N; cc++)
        {
            data[cc] = GetRandom();
            indexes[cc] = cc;
        }
    }

    // Clone is nessesary as Array.Sort is done in place, ie the next call will be incorrectly given a pre-sorted list
    private T[] GetTestData() => (T[]) data.Clone();
    private int[] GetTestDataIndex() => (int[])indexes.Clone();

    [Benchmark]
    public virtual void Sort()
    {
        Array.Sort(GetTestData());
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public virtual void SortMaintainIndex()
    {
        Array.Sort(GetTestData(), GetTestDataIndex());
    }

    [Benchmark]
    public virtual void SortWithLinq()
    {
        int cc = 0;
        var withIndex = GetTestData()
                  .Select(x => (cc++, x))
                  .OrderBy(x => x.x)
                  .ToArray();
    }
```

In terms of speed there is no comparison:
Source here https://gist.github.com/guylangston/cd9a0719d467f020eba46c6d0beb0584

```
BenchmarkDotNet=v0.10.14, OS=Windows 10.0.17134
Intel Core i7-3930K CPU 3.20GHz (Ivy Bridge), 1 CPU, 12 logical and 6 physical cores
.NET Core SDK=2.1.300
  [Host]     : .NET Core 2.1.0 (CoreCLR 4.6.26515.07, CoreFX 4.6.26515.06), 64bit RyuJIT
  DefaultJob : .NET Core 2.1.0 (CoreCLR 4.6.26515.07, CoreFX 4.6.26515.06), 64bit RyuJIT


            Method |     N |        Mean |      Error |     StdDev |      Median |
------------------ |------ |------------:|-----------:|-----------:|------------:|
              Sort |  1000 |    35.85 us |  0.3234 us |  0.2700 us |    35.76 us |
 SortMaintainIndex |  1000 |    60.82 us |  0.2280 us |  0.1780 us |    60.76 us |
      SortWithLinq |  1000 |   172.26 us |  3.3984 us |  3.7773 us |   170.75 us |
              Sort | 10000 |   611.82 us | 13.8881 us | 18.0584 us |   602.77 us |
 SortMaintainIndex | 10000 |   889.25 us | 18.6503 us | 28.4810 us |   874.06 us |
      SortWithLinq | 10000 | 2,484.35 us | 57.8378 us | 54.1015 us | 2,476.72 us |
```

Comment: On thing I found tricky where the argument names on public static void Array.Sort (Array keys, Array items); which appear the wrong way around from a callers perspective

Answer (score 0):

You could make an array of KeyValuePairs, then sort by value:

```
Array.Sort(array, (left, right) => left.Value.CompareTo(right.Value))
```

But the Array.Sort(Array, Array) looks good too.